# How to divide a list of values by a number in command line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, arithmetic, bc

I am trying to translate a simple program to the command line using unix utilities. For example, if I have a frequency list (after piping through uniq and sort)

```
5 x
4 y
1 z
```

I want to print out, instead of the frequencies, the fraction of the times they occur:

```
0.5 x
0.4 y
0.1 z
```

(I have a python program that does this, but I wanted to know if this could be done through the command line itself.)

So far, I have tried to compute the sum

```
<...>| awk -F" " '{print $1}' | tr '\n' +; echo 0 | bc
```

but this is just giving me the output `5+1+4+0` without computing it.

EDIT: I got the sum . I modified the above command to

```
<...>| awk -F" " '{print $1}' | echo $(tr '\n' +; echo 0) | bc > sum
```

and the correct result is stored in sum. Now I just want to divide the original list by sum and display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{ f[$2] = $1; SUM += $1} END { for (i in f) { print f[i]/SUM, i } }' </tmp/data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the summing in awk, and the dividing as well. This will be simpler than invoking `bc` since you have other data on each line.

This prints the sum of the first field of the input lines:

```
awk '{sum += $1} END {print $1}'
```

So you can save the input data, compute the sum, and continue processing the data.

```
data=$(…)
sum=$(printf '%s\n' "$data" | awk '{sum += $1} END {print $1}')
printf '%s\n' "$data" | awk -v sum="$sum" '{ $1 /= sum; print }'
```

Or you might [make a single pass in awk, retaining all the data in memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34305/how-to-divide-a-list-of-values-by-a-number-in-command-line/34308#34308).